# Pandas mean function rounds output to multiples of 0.25

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have this problem where the `mean()` function on a Pandas DataFrame column returns a number rounded to a multiple of 0.25.
My dataframe called groups looks like this:

```
    Period Svarer den tilbudte pris til dine forventninger?  Count  Rating
40  2022-2                                    Som forventet     28    3.00
41  2023-1                          Billigere end forventet      4    4.00
42  2023-1                             Dyrere end forventet     10    2.00
43  2023-1                       Meget dyrere end forventet      3    1.00
44  2023-1                                    Som forventet     23    3.00
```

It has a Period, a Question, a Count and a Rating column. I want to calculate averages for every period's rating. In the case above, the average rating in the period 2023-1 should be

```
(4 * 4.0 + 10 * 2.0 + 3 * 1.0 + 23 * 3.0) / (4 + 10 + 3 + 23) = 108 / 40 = 2.7
```

Pandas, however, seems to think it's `2.5`.

Here is my function:

```py
def create_bar_chart(df: pd.DataFrame, question: str):
    groups = df.groupby(['Period', question]).size().reset_index(name='Count')

    groups['Rating'] = groups.apply(lambda row: to_rating(question, row[question]), axis=1)
    groups['Rating'] = groups['Rating'].astype(float)
    print(groups.dtypes)
    print(groups.tail(5))

    for period in groups['Period'].unique():
        period_ratings = groups.loc[groups['Period'] == period, 'Rating']
        mean_rating = period_ratings.mean()
        print(f'{period}: {mean_rating:.4f}')

    # matplotlib code...
```

From the output, I can see that I have the following types

```
Period                                               object
Svarer den tilbudte pris til dine forventninger?     object
Count                                                 int64
Rating                                              float64
dtype: object
```

and that all the means are multiples of 0.25:

```
2018-1: 3.2500
2018-2: 3.0000
2019-1: 3.0000
2019-2: 2.5000
2020-1: 3.0000
2020-2: 2.7500
2021-1: 2.5000
2021-2: 2.7500
2022-1: 3.0000
2022-2: 2.5000
2023-1: 2.5000
```

Very strange. Have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were not computing the weighted average, but a simple average (`period_ratings.mean()`: `(4+2+1+3)/4 = 2.5`.

A simple way to compute a weighted average would to use a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`numpy.average`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.average.html) and weights:

```
out = (df.groupby('Period')
         .apply(lambda g: np.average(g['Rating'], weights=g['Count']))
      )
```

Or, manually with the ratio of two [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html) after computing the product of `Count` and `Rating`:

```
out = (df.eval('Sum = Count*Rating').groupby('Period')
       [['Count', 'Sum']].sum().eval('Sum/Count')
       )
```

Output:

```
Period
2022-2    3.0
2023-1    2.7
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to mozway's answer, I found a solution.
It's easier to understand, if I just write my own function `avg_rating` for this one-off script. It's simpler to adjust to my own specifications.

```py
def avg_rating(period: pd.DataFrame):
    """Calculate the average 1-5 rating for a period."""
    total = 0
    for _, row in period.iterrows():
        total += row['Count'] * row['Rating']
    return total / period['Count'].sum()


def period_averages(df: pd.DataFrame, question: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Create a dataframe with the average rating for each period."""
    groups = (
        df.groupby(['Period', question])
        .size()
        .reset_index(name='Count')
    )
    groups['Rating'] = groups.apply(lambda row: to_rating(question, row[question]), axis=1)
    groups['Rating'] = groups['Rating'].astype(float)
    groups = groups.dropna()

    period_averages = []
    for period in groups['Period'].unique():
        period_ratings = groups.loc[groups['Period'] == period, ['Rating', 'Count']]
        period_averages.append((period, avg_rating(period_ratings)))
    return pd.DataFrame(period_averages, columns=['Period', question])
```

It creates a dataframe where every period has a 1-5 rating that is an average.

```
    Period  Svarer den tilbudte pris til dine forventninger?
0   2018-1                                          2.823529
1   2018-2                                          2.885714
2   2019-1                                          2.781818
```